# Getting a part of a string and outputting it to another string

Tags: c#, string, output

Hi so i'm not exactly sure if the title justifies this question I'm not too good at phrasing sorry.

But what i'm trying to do is um like:

```
String joggingResults = ",Distance: 2.4km, Duration: 14minutes,";
```

And ideally, I would like to search joggingResults for " , " and output the words beside it.. and stops when it finds another " , " ... Does this make any sense? haha

My expected result would be something like this but each line is on a new string:

> Distance: 2.4km
>   Duration: 14minutes

I hope someone helps me out tysm

Comment: You are looking to create a list of strings from a single string based on a given separator. What have you tried already?

You should also edit your question to remove the unnecessary and distracting emotes, faces, and conversational locution.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: *And ideally, I would like to search joggingResults for " , " ....*. Have you tried that? it sounds like a good starting direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

joggingResults.Split(',')

Will give you a collection of strings split where the commas are.

Comment: Thanks :P that did help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can split using ',' and then loop through the array and display the results.

```
var results = joggingResults.Split(',');
foreach(var item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Note:- Assuming it is a console application. You can display it as per your type of application.